# Empty values inserted to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying get posted values inserted into table but every time I get empty values inserted.

```
      <form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    <button name="submit" value="send" type="submit">SUBSCRIBE</button>
      </form>


<?php
      $email = $_POST['email']
      $name = $_POST['name']

      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'x', 'x', 'x')
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

      $query = "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email)" .
        "VALUES ('$name', '$email')";

      $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('Error querying database.');

      mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `name` attribute in your `<input>` fields:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

FYI, you could have easily caught this by using `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your file or using a tool like Firebug to see no values were being sent to the server. You also could have done `echo $query` and saw there were no values. This is all basic debugging skills.

Comment: Don't you love the ignorance questions bring to the table! Good answer as always John.